# Contacts Web Database site in SharePoint Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database, contacts, access-services

I created a site of type Contacts Web Database under a team site collection in order to maintain some contacts.

As soon as I created the Contacts Web Database site on the homepage under the 'Address Book' tab there is an error message:

> An Error has occurred, Click here to try again

and the same error repeated in the Datasheet tab as well.

I created some sample contacts in the Access and when I sync they are updating in the Report Center tab of the Contacts Web Database, but the error in the 'Address Book' and 'Data Sheet' tabs happens again.

Made sure that the Access service in the Central Admin is configured and on, and also created a database to use for this Access DB.

Comment: Have you checked Access Services status in Central Admin? You should also check your ULS logs.

Comment: You should also check your Windows Application/System event logs.

Comment: To be able to answer this question we need some logging information to get more error details.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? If not I would check the version of SQL being used I believe for Access Services you need SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: When debugging this issue, you can configure the level of "Diagnostic Logging" within Central administration. This may help capture details that don't normally get logged. This is found in:
Central Administration > Operations > Diagnostic Logging

Comment: Benny, Is there a particular reason you are trying to use Access Services rather than SharePoint's Contact list? bob

Comment: it might be a permissions error with the account associated with Access Services.

Answer (score 1):

1-Access Services is installed part of the SharePoint 2010 Enterprise CAL
2-Make sure Service Infrastructure is enabled

Answer (score 0):

If you or someone else is still having this issue, you should open SharePoint Management shell and type:

**Set-SPLogLevel -traceseverity VerboseEx**

then type:

**New-SPLogFile**

then reproduce the issue a couple of times

type **New-SPLogFile** once more

Type **clear-sploglevel**

Then copy the log that encompasses when you reproduced the issue, so that we can look deeper into the issue, and save that file somewhere and provide a view link.